# How do I determine the remote endpoint a UDP packet originates from?

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

The socket is created and bound, then the program receives data with recv(). The question is: How do I now determine from which host + port the packet originates so that I can send data back?
Note: C and Winsock is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`recvfrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120(VS.85).aspx) instead, it can return the source port and address